# Continuos functions with compact support on a closed interval

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

I have a doubt about compact support functions. Let $f \in C_c([a,b])$, continuous with compact support in [a,b]. Is it always true that $f(a)=f(b)=0?$. I'm asking since in some exercises with these functions, my notes conclude that $f(a)=f(b)=0$, while, for instance, in the last problem I saw, they provide $f(x)=1 \ \ \forall x \in [0,1]$, as an example of function in $C_c([0,1])$. If I consider only the interval $ [0,1] $ as my topological space, is $[0,1]$ compact? I would say yes, since it is bounded and closed ( if I'm not wrong X is both open and closed in X) and $[0,1]$ is finite dimensional. So if $[0,1]$ is compact, I don't see why it should be $f(a)=f(b)=0$.

Comment: You are right. Just having a compact support does not imply $f(a)=f(b)=0$. The function $f(x)=1$ is indeed a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Every function in $C[0,1]$ has compact support. On the other hand if  a function $f$ in $C(a,b)$ has compact support then $f(a)=f(b)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is a function from $[a,b]$ to $\Bbb R$, then it has compact support by definition, because $[a,b]$ is compact in $[a,b]$ (**edited to add:** but see Sam Wong's comment below). So we can't deduce $f(a)=f(b)=0$.

If, on the other hand, $f$ is a function defined on the whole of $\Bbb R$, and is continuous on the whole of $\Bbb R$, then we must have $f(a)=f(b)=0$.

So it really depends on the exact definition of $C_c([a,b])$.

Comment: We need to be careful. The definition of support of $f$ is $\overline{\{f\neq 0\}}$, which may not be $[a,b]$ itself. By definition, the support of $f$ is closed in $[a,b]$. It is bounded because it is a subset of $[a,b]$. Therefore, the support of $f$ is compact (in $[a,b]$).

Comment: @SamWong: Yes, you are right. Thank you for pointing that out!