# Is it allowed speaking of value of a $f\in C_0^\infty(]a,b[)$ in a or b?

Tags: functions

Is it allowed speaking of value of a $f\in C_0^\infty(]a,b[)$ ($C^\infty$ functions with compact support) in a or b ? What sense to give to $f(b)=0$ ?

If we define a function over $C_0^\infty(]a,b[)$ , how could we know if it's well defined on a and b ,

Example : [Continuos functions with compact support on a closed interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345200/continuos-functions-with-compact-support-on-a-closed-interval) ,
In the answer of this question , we speak of an evaluation in a or b , and the context is C(a,b) (i think it's the english notation for C(]a,b[) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f\in\mathcal C_0^\infty (]a,b[)$. Since $f$ has compact support, there are real numbers $c,d$ with $a<c<d<b$ such that $f$ is $0$ outside of $[c,d]$. Therefore, $f(a) = f(b) = 0$ extends $f$ to a $ \mathcal C^\infty $ function on $[a,b]$